# How do I call on a method from a different class in a different file?

Tags: python, class, methods

Here is the class (from point.py):

```
class Point:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

   def adjacent(self, pt1, pt2):
      return ((pt1.x == pt2.x and abs(pt1.y - pt2.y) == 1) or
         (pt1.y == pt2.y and abs(pt1.x - pt2.x) == 1))

   def distance_sq(self, p1, p2):
      return (p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2
```

And say I have this function that is in a different file (actions.py):

```
import point

def find_nearest(world, pt, type):
   oftype = [(e, distance_sq(pt, entities.get_position(e)))
      for e in worldmodel.get_entities(world) if isinstance(e, type)]

   return nearest_entity(of type)
```

Notice how this function is calling distance_sq from point.py, when I try running this code, it complains that:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'distance_sq'
```

I can't remember the correct syntax for calling a method from a class in a different file! Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `point.Point(x, y).distance_sq()` or `a = point.Point(x,y)` then `a.distance_sq()`

Comment: Hmm, now it's complaining that: NameError: global name 'x' is not defined (I used the a = point.Point(x,y) option)

Comment: x, y are instance variables. You need to replace them with actual values like strings, integers or whatever they are intended to be...

Comment: Also your line `return nearest_entity(of type)` seems fishy to me...

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look at that. Thanks. :) Just curious, but does it matter what integer I put in? Or does that depend on the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0):

For your `Point` class, neither of the methods defined refer to the instance (`self`) at all. You should make these either functions in the `point` module, or if you prefer to keep them namespaced in the class, make them static methods:

```
class Point:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

   @staticmethod
   def adjacent(pt1, pt2):
      return ((pt1.x == pt2.x and abs(pt1.y - pt2.y) == 1) or
         (pt1.y == pt2.y and abs(pt1.x - pt2.x) == 1))

   @staticmethod
   def distance_sq(p1, p2):
      return (p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2
```

Then import the `Point` class from `point` if  you use the `staticmethod` approach:

```
 from point import Point

 ... Point.distance_sq(pt, entities.get_position(e))
```

Or import `point` and use `point.distance_sq` if you use functions instead.

Possibly a better approach, if both `pt` and `entities.get_position(e)` are instances of `Point`, would be to make `pt1` in both methods always be the current instance:

```
def adjacent(self, point):
    return (
        (self.x == point.x and abs(self.y - point.y) == 1) or
        (self.y == point.y and abs(self.x - point.x) == 1)
    )

def distance_sq(self, point):
    return (self.x - point.x)**2 + (self.y - point.y)**2
```

Then you don't need to import `point` at all, just do:

```
pt.distance_sq(entities.get_position(e))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not call a member method of a class directly without creating an instance of that class first. It looks like your `distance_sq` method should be outside class declaration like:

In point.py:

```
class Point:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

   def adjacent(self, pt1, pt2):
      return ((pt1.x == pt2.x and abs(pt1.y - pt2.y) == 1) or
         (pt1.y == pt2.y and abs(pt1.x - pt2.x) == 1))

def distance_sq(p1, p2):
    return (p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2
```

Then you can call this function like:

```
import point
point.distance_sq(point1, point2)
```

Or, the good way will be to create a classmethod like:

In point.py:

```
class Point:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

   def adjacent(self, pt1, pt2):
      return ((pt1.x == pt2.x and abs(pt1.y - pt2.y) == 1) or
         (pt1.y == pt2.y and abs(pt1.x - pt2.x) == 1))

   @classmethod
   def distance_sq(cls, p1, p2):
       return (p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2
```

Then, call it like:

```
import point
point.Point.distance_sq(point1, point2)
```